# How to cumsum streak with reset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'col2':[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],'col3':[.5,.5,.3,.2,.1,.4,.7,.4,.5,.3,.2,.4,.5,.6]})
```

I need a running sum of col3, but the sum should reset whenever col1 changes or if there is a zero in col2. I should return something like in the following:
 [mock output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuhxx.png)

I tried the following:

```
df['cum'] = df.groupby([df.col1, df.col2]).col3.cumsum()
```

However, it is not resetting correctly. It resets but continues summing the the subsequent rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a shot here

```
zeros = df.col2.eq(0)
vals = df.groupby(['col1', df.col2.ne(df.col2.shift()).cumsum()]).col3.cumsum()

df['id'] = np.where(zeros, 0, vals)
```

---

Explanation:

Whenever `col2` is `0`, just set `0`. Else, just set the `cumsum` of the grouped values.

Comment: @pandachii so glad I could help ;)

Comment: one mistake I realized, if I wanted the cumsum to start after the first instance of 1 in col2. How would the code change? The new expected output would be 0,0.5,0.8,0,0,0.1,0.5,0,0,0,.3,0,0,0

Comment: @pandachii thats the expected output for which input ?

Comment: the original input from the post